# Mocking a Peewe class does not return value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, peewee

Mock a peewe class to mock the class attributes

models.py

```
import peewe

class A():
    human = CharField()


class B():
    first = CharField()
    second = ForeignKeyField(B, related_name="addresses")
```

test.py
    from mock import patch

```
def build_A_model():
   var = models.A()
   var.human = "yes"

def build_B_model(A_fake_model):
   var1 = models.B()
   var1.first = "test"
   var1.second = A_fake_model
   return var1

@patch(models.A)
 class testing(unittest.TestCase):
     def test1(self, A_mock):
         A_fake_model = build_A_model()
         B_model = build_B_model(A_fake_model)
         expected = {
            "first": "test",
            "second": {
                "human": "yes"
            },
          }
         # some function to searlize B_model to json
         result = json_searlized_data
         self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

**Task:** Trying to mock A_Model and B_model to get the desired expected result:

**Issue:** Mock_A class returns a Magic Mock() instead of returning a value

**Error:**  human: MagicMock name='xxxxx' id='139670936802896'"

**Question:** How to return a value of mocked class_A model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything:

```
def build_A_model():
   var = models.A()
   var.human = "yes"
```

Add a return statement yo.